# Force repeated rows with different derived value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple query

```
SELECT  Group, Value, NULL AS MONTH from tbl_A
```

which returns

```
 Group   Value  Month
 A       100    NULL
 B       110    NULL
```

I'm seeking results that return

```
Group   Value  Month
A       100    1
A       100    2
A       100    3
...
B       110    1
B       110    2
B       110    3
...
```

In other words, I need to be able to define a list of values and repeat each result row for each value in the defined list of "months". They are actually dates, but I just used integers here for clarity.

Comment: `tbl_a CROSS JOIN your_list_of_months`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `VALUES` clause to define a [Table Value Constructor (TVC)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/) . Then `CROSS APPLY` in order to get required result set:

```
SELECT  [Group], Value, x.y AS MONTH 
from tbl_A
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) x(y)
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9348/1)

Comment: This did it! I had a feeling CROSS APPLY was the trick, but couldn't get the implementation down. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try `CROSS join` as below

```
select Group, Value, MONTH 
from tbl_A
cross join (select 1 as MONTH 
            union all
            select 2
            union all
            select 3
            union all
            select 4
            union all
            select 5
            union all
            select 6
            union all
            select 7
            union all
            select 8
            union all
            select 9
            union all
            select 10
            union all
            select 11
            union all
            select 12) B
order by Group, Value, MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table `Months` (or `tbl_B` if you want to keep your naming convention) and populate it with your `Month` values, then it should be a simple matter of doing this:

```
SELECT a.[Group], a.Value, b.Month
FROM tbl_A a INNER JOIN tbl_B b
ON 1=1
```

This will join all values from each table because of the `ON 1=1` (which is always true, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the trick:

```
DECLARE @tMonths TABLE (
[Number]    int)
INSERT  INTO @tMonths([Number])
VALUES  (1)
, (2)
, (3)

SELECT  *
FROM    groups g
INNER   JOIN    @tMonths m
ON  1 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a list of integers (what list of months is):

```
SELECT [Group], Value, Month
FROM TBL
cross apply (
     SELECT DISTINCT MONTH = number 
  FROM master..[spt_values] 
  WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 12) A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d330/3)

Answer (score 0):

variant using recursive cte

```
WITH M
AS
(   SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n = n + 1
    FROM M
    WHERE n <= 12),    
tbl_A
AS
(   SELECT *
    FROM (
    VALUES ( 'A', 100, NULL ),
           ( 'B', 100, NULL )
    ) AS t([GROUP], Value, [Month])
)
SELECT A.[GROUP],
       A.Value,
       M.n AS [Month]
FROM       tbl_A AS A
CROSS JOIN M
ORDER BY [GROUP],
         [Month]
```